European iPhone 12 Mini models usable in USA?
We have two iPhones 12 Minis that we bought used in Germany. Their model numbers are MGDM3J/A and MGDX3TA/A.
Can I use these models to make calls from the USA when we are visiting the USA (New York City)?

I answered a similar question but going from the US to Europe (UK). Your phone will work, but there will be differences in the bands your phone can access. You may see things like weak coverage in certain areas or slow(er) Internet downloads.
